# Difference betwen types of PCIe lanes in server systems

Tags: server, pcie, nvidia

I've been trying to learn about nVidia's GPU Direct Storage for the purposes of database systems, like [pg-strom](https://heterodb.github.io/pg-strom/ssd2gpu/). GPU Direct is a technology leveraging PCI Express' ability to perform PCIe to PCIe transfers without involving CPU or main memory. I've realized my knowledge about PCI Express as a technology is quite lacking here though…

I'm considering a scenario where I would like to match a single PCI-Express 5.0 16-lane GPU (with theoretical bandwidth of 63 GB/s, apparently realistically around 50 GB/s) to eight PCI-Express 4.0 4-lane NVMe drives (again, theoretical 63 GB/s, realistically 55 GB/s), to stream data from the drives and perform filtering and aggregation within GPU.

Reading the article on [fourth gen Xeon Scalables](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/fourth-generation-xeon-scalable-family-overview.html) we see that they are supposedly supporting 80 PCI-Express lanes, which would be just fine for this scenario: GPU takes 16 lanes, drives take 32 lanes. But then I see this statement:

> 48 lanes North/ 32 lanes South of socket

which suggests to me that it may really matter which specific lanes are used?

At the same time [nVidia states that DGX A100 (that use AMD Rome CPUs) systems have](https://docs.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage/design-guide/index.html):

> two CPU sockets, and each has two PCIe trees

Do these two PCIe trees correspond to the "north" and "south" lanes, or is it a different concept?

Looking at an block diagram of an example motherboard ([MNL-2512](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/superserver/2U/MNL-2515.pdf), PDF warning), I don't see any explicit "south bridge" either. I am guessing here that PE0, PE1, PE2 are probably somehow separate from PE3 and PE4 based on the fact they are visualized separately?

[This nVidia presentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/cuda/docs/GPUDirect_Technology_Overview.pdf) (PDF warning) suggests that as long as devices are under a single IOH/CPU, then "it should work". But that presentation talks about GPUs and network cards, not NVMe drives.

At the same time, does it matter that this scenario mixes 4.0 and 5.0 devices? Can direct PCIe-to-PCIe transfers happen at full speed between these devices?

Thank you!